# Who can I fix a block before reading stream with python-requests?

Tags: python, http, python-3.x, python-requests

I have a problem, my get requests is blocking even with stream param True:

```
import requests
import pprint

c = 'http://www.ticketfly.com/'

s = requests.Session()
s.max_redirects = 3
s.timeout = 3
s.max_retries = 3
res = None

print('Start')
res = s.request('GET', c, stream=True, timeout=2)

print('Start reading from stream')
print(res.status_code)
for line in res.iter_lines():
    print(line)

print('end')
```

My program can't skip over:

```
res = s.request('GET', c, stream=True, timeout=2)
```

Comment: It works for me. Linux Mint, Python 3.3.2, requests 2.3.0